# attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public error for isCancelled

Tags: java, boolean, swingworker

So i have this code for isCancelled in SwingWorker

```
boolean isCancelled() return true;
```

and its giving me the error

> attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public error

I dont know how to fix it. Can anyone help me? Thank you

Comment: make it `public boolean isCancelled()` rather than just `boolean isCancelled()`

Comment: @KarthikT i tried this already and it gave me the error that it cannot override the final method in SwingWorker

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you need braces around your method body.

Secondly, the way you're currently declaring it uses *package* access, but the [`isCancelled`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#isCancelled%28%29) method is public, so you'd have to override it with another public method.

Thirdly, the method is `final` anyway, so you can't override it in the first place. It's not clear what you're trying to achieve, but this isn't the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Because if **override** methods you use same access in superclass or extend(package -> protected -> public).

Example if superclass:

```
boolean isCancelled(){}; // package local default access

protected boolean isCancelled(){};

public boolean isCancelled(){};
```

In your sub class use(relatively):

```
@Override
boolean isCancelled(){}; //or add  protected or public

@Override
protected boolean isCancelled(){};//or change public

@Override
public boolean isCancelled(){};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this like the previous poster said:

```
@Override
public boolean isCancelled(){
 return true;
}
```

But you may also want to consider whether you really need a method at all, when you may only need to have a variable:

```
public boolean isCancelled = true;
```